# Graphic modeler with if Statement

Tags: qgis-3, qgis-modeler

Is it possible to use a boolean as an input and if it is true then the field will be created?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use the following expression to connect the boolean input to the tool:

```
If(@blnCreateField, 'FieldName', '')
```

---

For clarity, `@blnCreateField` returns either `True` or `False` depending if the checkbox for the parameter was checked or not. So the `if` statement checks if the first condition is true and, if it is, then return `'FieldName'` else return nothing.

Comment: the model does the job well, but when I export it to python then I get an error like "Unable to execute algorithm
Field name is not set. Please enter a field name". I think it is a bug.

Comment: @kjp - You should probably ask this as a [follow-up question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) to this one and include the code of the exported python script. It may be that the code will need to be edited to run it as a script.